# Jupyter notebook is displayed partially in French

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using **Jupyter** for Python programming on **Windows 10** and some of the text is translated in French but not all of it (which makes it kinda annoying).

[image]

Does someone know how to change the display language?

I am unable to find the answer on internet because every time I'm searching for "language" it shows me answers for programming languages (R, Python, etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. Had to change the language settings in Chrome.

Comment: follow the answer provided by Chinh052010 in https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4158 and it works!

Answer (score 3):

(Internet Explorer): Just go to your internet options in the settings, Choose 'Languages' from the general tab. A new pop up will open with all listed/available languages in it. Simply remove everything except your required language.

(Google Chrome): Go to settings, choose 'Advanced'. Select Languages option. Set what language you are looking for in the mentioned place.

Answer (score 3):

A solution without changing browser language:

Go to `Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\i18n` (if you experience this problem in some virtual env -> go to `Anaconda3\envs\yourenv\Lib\site-packages\notebook\i18n`).

Here you have directories named as languages. For me, it was enough to delete the directory with a language which i dont want to be used in `Jupyter`. There still were some other languages left in the `i18n` but fortunately `Jupyter` used English anyway.

The source: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4158#issuecomment-652161294 says that you have to rename the language which you are annoyed by.

Comment: I tried the PATH variable, settings in the browser but neither worked. Finally, this worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In windows, set an environment variable LANG=en_US. That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but my browser had the two languages register in the settings (French and English). You need to put English at the top priority :

As you can see here：

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question was asked years ago but I have noticed this situation in Arch Linux while running the `jupyter notebook` command.

Recently, I have fixed this issue on my OS via setting the `LANGUAGE` environment variable to `"en_US"`. I think this might help anyone searching for solutions.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Firefox, be sure that the only language is English[Firefox settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCzJR.png), but if you are using other navigator, it is the same things.