# Part of the notebook in French

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

For some reason I don't understand, some UI elements of my Jupyter Notebook are being displayed in French, while I'd like them to be in English, like the rest of my programming tools. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRub1.png).

Instead of iPython's usual `In [1]:`, it's written in French. French is my system language, but I don't think any of the elements installed are in French, might it be Jupyter, iPython ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqsyt.png)) or even Anaconda. As you can see, I'm also using [Jupyter Themes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes), but I doubt it's modifying any language-related UI element. Do you know how I can fix that?

For information, I'm using:

- Python 3.7.1
- Anaconda 4.5.11
- Jupyter 4.4.0
- Jupyter Themes 0.19.6

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Best regards,

Comment: From reading this question and answer, it looks like it takes the language information from your web browser settings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52949429/9742036

Answer (score 1):

A solution without changing browser language:

Go to Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\i18n (if you experience this problem in some virtual env -> go to Anaconda3\envs\yourenv\Lib\site-packages\notebook\i18n).

Here you have directories named as languages. For me, it was enough to delete the directory with a language which i dont want to be used in Jupyter. There still were some other languages left in the i18n but fortunately Jupyter used English anyway.

The source: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4158#issuecomment-652161294 says that you have to rename the language which you are annoyed by.