# When i create a new jupyter notebook (python 3.9), half of the jupyter notebook settings are written in russian (cyrillic) the other half in english

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, cyrillic, python-3.9

Why is this happening and how can i change it?
I already tried to install and uninstall jupyter in different ways (anaconda, pip etc.) but it still won't work.
It appears that jupyter before creating a new notebook doesn't have that problem...
The menu labels and dropdown options are english, but as soon as i open some settings, they're all russian.
[Screenshot notebook menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtkM2.png)

I do not use a chrome translator or anything similar and my windows language is set to german.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, there is a post with the same problem but the answers don't worked for me, I hope they works for you: [Jupyter notebook is displayed partially in French](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52667314/jupyter-notebook-is-displayed-partially-in-french)

Comment: omg thank you so much! i thought i already tried that, but now it worked!